# SQL Pivot Table dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I've tried so hard to understand how to create a pivot table in SQL, but I can't manage it!

I have the following columns:

```
link_id   route_section   date_1    StartHour     AvJT    data_source
.......   .............  .......   ...........   ......  ............
```

With 600,000 rows of data.

I need them in the following pivot table;

- `date_1` StartHour as column headings
- `link_id` as the row heading
- `AvJT` as the data
- with `data_source` = '1' as the filter.

**PIVOT TABLE**

```
Link_ID 
date_1      StartHour    00001a    000002a    000003a    000004a
20/01/2014    8           456       4657        556       46576
21/01/2014    8           511       4725        601       52154
22/01/2014    8           468       4587        458       47585
23/01/2014    8           456       4657        556       46576
24/01/2014    8           456       4657        556       46576
25/01/2014    8           456       4657        556       46576
26/01/2014    8           456       4657        556       46576
```

I've managed to get the following code, this works but only gives me date_1 as column heading and not StartHour additionally, or with the filter as date_source = '1'.

```
    Use [C1_20132014]

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Link_ID)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Link_ID FROM C1_May_Routes) AS Link_ID

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Date_1, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM C1_May_Routes
    PIVOT(SUM(AvJT) 
          FOR Link_ID IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Thanks for any help,

Henry

Comment: Can you provide a link to where it's been solved elsewhere?

Comment: I think this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: See this post: http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: Is there always 4 columns? If so you can do this in a crosstab and no need to make it dynamic.

Comment: How do you do it in crosstab? @SeanLange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you will select the values in a column to show as column in pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + AvJT + ']', '[' + AvJT + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT AvJT FROM YourTable) PV  
               ORDER BY AvJT
```

Now pivot the query

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT date_1, StartHour,AvJT, data_source 
                 FROM YourTable
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 -- Values in each dynamic column
                 SUM(data_source)
                 FOR AvJT IN (' + @cols + ')                      
            ) p;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ff56/1) to view result

If you want to do it to where column names are not dynamic, you can do the below query

```
SELECT DATE_1,STARTHOUR,
MIN(CASE WHEN AvJT='00001a' THEN data_source END) [00001a],
MIN(CASE WHEN AvJT='00002a' THEN data_source END) [00002a],
MIN(CASE WHEN AvJT='00003a' THEN data_source END) [00003a],
MIN(CASE WHEN AvJT='00004a' THEN data_source END) [00004a]
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY  DATE_1,STARTHOUR
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ff56/2) to view result

**EDIT :**

I am updating for your updated question.

Declare a variable for filtering `data_source`

```
DECLARE @DATASOURCE VARCHAR(20) = '1'
```

Instead of `QUOTENAME`, you can use another format to get the columns for pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + Link_ID + ']', '[' + Link_ID + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Link_ID FROM C1_May_Routes WHERE data_source=@DATASOURCE) PV  
               ORDER BY Link_ID
```

Now pivot

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 -- We will select the data that has to be shown for pivoting
                 -- with filtered data_source
                 SELECT date_1, StartHour,AvJT, Link_ID
                 FROM C1_May_Routes
                 WHERE data_source = '+@DATASOURCE+'
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 -- Values in each dynamic column
                 SUM(AvJT)
                 -- Select columns from @cols 
                 FOR Link_ID IN (' + @cols + ')                      
            ) p;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c422/4) to view result

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I cannot get it to work though!

Comment: What happened? What is your problem you are facing? @hc91

Comment: I need AvJT to be the data that fills the table. Data_source just needs to be a filter so I can make 4 different tables - source 1, source 2 etc. These should be the variables that go into the table - Date_1 smalldatetime, StartHour smallint, Link_ID VARCHAR(50), AvJT int

Comment: Do u mean that u want to filter by date like Date_1 between some dates ?@hc91

Comment: Can u  provide some sample data to the first table? @hc91

Comment: I have updated. Feel free to ask for any changes @hc91

Comment: Thank you so much! That's so helpful.

Comment: Is there any way of removing all the columns that do not fulfil the criteria?

Comment: I didn't get u. What criteria? @hc91

Comment: Well at the moment the WHERE data_source = '+@DATASOURCE+' works well, with only values being displayed for that particular data source. However, the links (across the x axis) remain meaning I need an excel macro to delete them. Also, is there any way to replace 'NULL' with blanks?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227924/row-and-column-total-in-dynamic-pivot/28233641#28233641 . Here I have used `@NullToZeroCols` variable. You have to change `ISNULL(['+Link_ID+'],0)` to `ISNULL(['+Link_ID+'],'')` and in pivot query, instead of `SELECT * FROM` use `SELECT date_1, StartHour,'+ @NullToZeroCols +'  FROM` . @hc91

Answer (score 0):

A crosstab would be something like this. FWIW, I would recommend using better column names than 00001a. Give your column names some meaning so they are easier to work with.

```
with SortedData as
(
    SELECT date_1
        , StartHour
        , AvJT
        , data_source 
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by date_1 order by AvJT) AS RowNum
    FROM YourTable
)

select date_1
    , StartHour
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 1 then AvJT end) as [00001a]
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 2 then AvJT end) as [00002a]
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 3 then AvJT end) as [00003a]
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 4 then AvJT end) as [00004a]
from SortedData
```

Comment: Oh, I see, apologies. The column names are link_id's and there are around 6,000 of them.