# Row and column total in dynamic pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot, cube, dynamic-pivot

In SQL Server 2008, I have a table (tblStock) with 3 columns:

> - PartCode (NVARCHAR (50))
> - StockQty (INT)
> - Location (NVARCHAR(50))

some example data below:

```
    PartCode    StockQty    Location
   .........   .........    .........
    A              10        WHs-A
    B              22        WHs-A
    A               1        WHs-B
    C              20        WHs-A
    D              39        WHs-F
    E               3        WHs-D
    F               7        WHs-A
    A               9        WHs-C
    D               2        WHs-A
    F              54        WHs-E
```

How to create procedure to get the result as below?

```
PartCode    WHs-A   WHs-B   WHs-C   WHs-D   WHs-E   WHs-F   Total
........    .....   .....   .....  ......   .....   .....   .....
A            10       1       9       0       0       0      20
B            22       0       0       0       0       0      22
C            20       0       0       0       0       0      20
D             2       0       0       0       0      39      41
E             0       0       0       3       0       0       3
F             7       0       0       0      54       0      61
Total        61       1       9       3      54      39     167
```

Your help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
SELECT * INTO #tblStock
FROM
(
SELECT 'A' PartCode,  10 StockQty, 'WHs-A' Location
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',   22,  'WHs-A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',   1,   'WHs-B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',   20,  'WHs-A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D',   39,  'WHs-F'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E',   3,   'WHs-D'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F',   7,   'WHs-A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',   9,   'WHs-C'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D',   2,   'WHs-A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F',   54,  'WHs-E'
)TAB
```

Get the columns for dynamic pivoting and replace `NULL` with `zero`

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + Location + ']', '[' + Location + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM #tblStock) PV 
               ORDER BY Location 
-- Since we need Total in last column, we append it at last
SELECT @cols += ',[Total]'


--Varible to replace NULL with zero
DECLARE @NulltoZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @NullToZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT ',ISNULL(['+Location+'],0) AS ['+Location+']' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM #tblStock)TAB  
ORDER BY Location FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000) 

SELECT @NullToZeroCols += ',ISNULL([Total],0) AS [Total]'
```

You can use `CUBE` to find row and column total and replace `NULL` with `Total` for the rows generated from `CUBE`.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT PartCode,' + @NulltoZeroCols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT 
                 ISNULL(CAST(PartCode AS VARCHAR(30)),''Total'')PartCode, 
                 SUM(StockQty)StockQty , 
                 ISNULL(Location,''Total'')Location              
                 FROM #tblStock
                 GROUP BY Location,PartCode
                 WITH CUBE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(StockQty)
                 FOR Location IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN (PartCode=''Total'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,PartCode' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27f11/4) to view result**

**RESULT**

[image]

**NOTE : If you want `NULL` instead of `zero` as values, use `@cols` instead of `@NulltoZeroCols` in dynamic pivot code**

**EDIT :**

**1. Show only Row Total**

- Do not use the code `SELECT @cols += ',[Total]'` and `SELECT @NullToZeroCols += ',ISNULL([Total],0) AS [Total]'`.
- Use `ROLLUP` instead of `CUBE`.

[image]

**2. Show only Column Total**

- Use the code `SELECT @cols += ',[Total]'` and `SELECT @NullToZeroCols += ',ISNULL([Total],0) AS [Total]'`.
- Use `ROLLUP` instead of `CUBE`.
- Change `GROUP BY Location,PartCode` to `GROUP BY PartCode,Location`.
- Instead of `ORDER BY CASE WHEN (PartCode=''Total'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,PartCode`, use `WHERE PartCode<>''TOTAL'' ORDER BY PartCode`.

[image]

**UPDATE : To bring `PartName` for OP**

I am updating the below query to add `PartName` with result. Since `PartName` will add extra results with `CUBE` and to avoid confusion in `AND` or `OR` conditions, its better to join the pivoted result with the `DISTINCT` values in your source table.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT P.PartCode,T.PartName,' + @NulltoZeroCols + ' FROM 
             (                
                 SELECT 
                 ISNULL(CAST(PartCode AS VARCHAR(30)),''Total'')PartCode, 
                 SUM(StockQty)StockQty , 
                 ISNULL(Location,''Total'')Location              
                 FROM #tblStock
                 GROUP BY Location,PartCode
                 WITH CUBE                   
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(StockQty)
                 FOR Location IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            LEFT JOIN
            (  
                SELECT DISTINCT PartCode,PartName
                FROM #tblStock  
            )T
            ON P.PartCode=T.PartCode
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN (P.PartCode=''Total'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,P.PartCode' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37e0e/1) to view result**

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i need, thanks @Sarath Avanavu for your solution and explanation.

Comment: one more thing, any solution if i want to add more column (PartName) after PartCode? [PartCode,PartName,WHs-A,..,Total]

Comment: One partcode will have only 1 partname right? @Sokea

Comment: Could it be replaced the last NULL value in PartName with nothing?

Comment: Yes. It can be done using **ISNULL(T.PartName,'') AS PartName** or if u want nothing as string, use **ISNULL(T.PartName,'Nothing') AS PartName** @Sokea

Comment: tried, but got error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,P.PartCode'.

Comment: Thats because you have to use single quotes for two times in dynamic sql. Use **ISNULL(T.PartName,'''') AS PartName** or **ISNULL(T.PartName,''Nothing'') AS PartName**. Note : Its not double qoutes. Its 2 single qoutes together. @Sokea

Comment: I still have one problem with dynamic pivot in link here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290971/arithmetic-operators-against-dynamic-column-in-sql-server-2008?noredirect=1#comment44937479_28290971] pls. kindly check if you have any solution idea. thanks.

Comment: Please delete all the comments my friend so that it will be neat :) @Sokea

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `case based aggregation` to pivot the data

To get the `total` row use `union`

In case the `Location` values are not known in advance, you need to construct a `dynamic query`

you can also use `pivot` keyword to do the same.

```
select partCode,
 sum( case when Location='WHs-A' then StockQty
      else 0 end
    ) as 'Whs-A',
 sum( case when Location='WHs-B' then StockQty
      else 0 end
    ) as 'Whs-B',
sum(StockQty) as 'Total'
from tblStock
group by partCode
union all
select 'Total' as 'partCode',
sum( case when Location='WHs-A' then StockQty
    else 0 end ) as 'Whs-A',
sum( case when Location='WHs-B' then StockQty
    else 0 end) as 'Whs-B',
sum(StockQty) as 'Total'
from tblStock
```

Comment: thanks radar. anyway Location is unknown column, could you pls. provide dynamic query?