# SQL: How to Pivot a Table with Pivot Columns Sharing the Same Name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 version 10.50.1600.1.

I'm trying to pivot a table with strings but the pivot column shares the same name.  This is what my data looks like.

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| patient_ID | code_type | code_value |
+------------+-----------+------------+
|          1 | ICD9      | V70        |
|          1 | ICD9      | 401.9      |
|          1 | ICD9      | 616        |
|          1 | ICD9      | 338.21     |
|          2 | ICD9      | V10        |
|          2 | ICD9      | 250        |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

What I'm trying to get to is this ...

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| patient_id | ICD9_1 | ICD9_2 | ICD9_3 | ICD9_4 | ICD9_5 | ICD9_x |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|          1 | V70    | 401.9  | 616    | 338.21 | null   | null   |
|          2 | V10    | 250    | null   | null   | null   | null   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

ICD9_x can stretch to infinity because I don't know how many ICD9 codes there will be for a given patient.

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Thanks!

---

Update:

Thanks for all the help!  I have received two errors.  It looks like pivoting requires the values to be an int because of the sum right?  Is there a way to use the pivot table for string values?  The ICD9 codes are all strings.

Secondly, I hit an unexpected error.  It says that "the number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements."  Is there a solution for a large data set?

Thanks again!

Comment: Searvh for dynamic pivot...

Comment: You should use dynamic pivot, here is better explained: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068971/sql-pivot-table-dynamic]

Comment: Try assigning something unique to the patient or encounter.  a ROW_NUMBER() should get you there.  As far as it stretching to infinity, you have UP TO 68000 + 13000 (ICD10 and 9 respectively).  which well exceeds the 1024 max columns in SQL

Comment: Thanks all.  For dynamic pivots, does it work for strings?  I've searched about and all of the dynamic pivots sums the data.  Apologies, I'm still very new to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a primary key or any column to use for ordering to make sure the codes will be in the correct order?

If you have one then you can concatenate the code_type value to the output of:

```
row_number () OVER (PARTITION BY patient_ID, code_type ORDER BY patient_id, /* codes order column here */)
```

... And then you will be able to use PIVOT ( [technet info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ) with the concatenated values.

Here is some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
-- Preparing some demo data as per your sample:
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    patient_id INT,
    code_type VARCHAR(20),
    code_value VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @YourTable
    (patient_id, code_type, code_value)
VALUES
    (1, 'ICD9', 'V70'),
    (1, 'ICD9', '401.9'),
    (1, 'ICD9', '616'),
    (1, 'ICD9', '338.21'),
    (2, 'ICD9', 'V10'),
    (2, 'ICD9', '250')

-- That should look like your starting point:
SELECT * FROM @YourTable

-- Now we suffix the code_type:
SELECT
    patient_id, 
    code_type + '_' + cast(
            row_number () OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id, code_type ORDER BY patient_id, ID)
            AS VARCHAR(20)
        ) AS code_type, 
    code_value
FROM
    @YourTable

-- ... and finally we pivot:
SELECT
    patient_id,
    ICD9_1, 
    ICD9_2, 
    ICD9_3, 
    ICD9_4
FROM (
    SELECT
        patient_id, 
        code_type + '_' + cast(
                row_number () OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id, code_type ORDER BY patient_id, ID)
                AS VARCHAR(20)
            ) AS code_type, 
        code_value
    FROM
        @YourTable
) data
PIVOT (
    max(code_value)
    -- you need to list all here:
    FOR code_type IN (ICD9_1, ICD9_2, ICD9_3, ICD9_4)
) piv
```

Comment: Thanks! There is one more column that is a unique identifier for this table that is used as a primary key.  But after pivoting it, I plan to use the patient_id as the primary key.

I received an unexpected error though.  It says I exceed the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.  I didn't realize there was a limit.

Comment: Exceeded 4096? That sounds like you were trying to produce more than 4096 columns, while each patient seems to be on a separate row in your sample result - so to get 4096+ columns you should have had 4096+ rows per each patient on input, is that the case? Are you sure your codes counter is restarted from 1 for each patient_id?

Comment: I thought that might be the case but looking at the original data, it doesn't seem possible.  I have about 20k patients but the column I'm trying to pivot is only the diagnosis column, which should not exceed 20 columns when pivoted.

Secondly, can I pivot varchar's?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to pivot varchar - you will probably need to add an aggregation function in which case you can just use max(), but be careful - to make that work you will need to make sure the suffixed code_type is suffixed correctly (e.g. the counter / row_number resets for each customer and each row has a unique patient_id & suffixed code_type combination to avoid "hiding" data becasue of the max()). I will try to improve my post with an example to make it clear.

Comment: Just updated my post with a sample to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can Try something like this. I hope that Works for you.

```
DECLARE @cols as varchar(max)
DECLARE @query as varchar(max)

select  @cols = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t.code_type+CAST(row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by patient_id, code_type) as varchar(10)))
    FROM YOURTABLE as t
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))

select @query = 'select patient_id, ' + @cols + ' from
(select
code_type+CAST(row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by patient_id, code_type) as varchar(10)) as code_type, SUM(code_value) as code_value from YOURTABLE

group by
code_type+CAST(row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by patient_id, code_type) as varchar(10))) d

Pivot (SUM(code_value) for code_type in (' + @cols + ')) p'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately I have a lot of patients and got this error.

The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.  Is there another way to handle a large data set?

Comment: Also, in the subquery where you sum(code_value), code value is varchar.  Is this still possible?  I looked a a couple dynamic pivot table and all of them require summing the values.  Is there a way around this?  Thanks!